# When adding the numbers in excel, the result is giving an error instead of 0

Tags: excel

Excel column has 68 numbers. Add the first 67 numbers and the result is 0.2. However, when we add -0.2 to (line 68), the result is not 0.
I get the SUM error: 1.16573E-15

Numbers:

```
-0,5
-0,3
-0,5
-1
-2
-0,2
-0,3
4
14
-4
-0,3
-1
-1
-1
-5
0
-1
-1
-1
-0,2
-1
0
-1
-1
-3
-0,5
-1
-1
14
4
-1,8
-1
-0,5
-0,5
-0,5
-1
-1
-1
0
0
0
-1
-0,5
-0,2
-0,2
-0,5
0
-1
-2,3
4
14
-2
-2
-0,2
-0,5
-0,2
-1
-1
-0,2
-1
-1
-1
-0,2
0
-0,5
-0,2
-1
-0,2
```

Comment: That is not an error, it's a very small number.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

Answer (score 0):

Computers have the tendency to be inaccurate while working with numbers with decimals (called floating point numbers). For Excel, more information is given in [this URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result)

By the way, it's very probable that the value 0.2 you have at 67 numbers in fact equals 0.2 + 1.16573E-15.